# Is there any way to gather or produce a blank, solid, white block in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to gather or produce a blank, solid, white block in Minecraft?  Iron blocks come kind of close, but you can see markings on them.  White stained clay comes close, but it's got a little bit of red mixed in.  Etc.  Is there anything that's just pure, blank white?  This has to be in vanilla though.

**EDIT**

It sounds like a resource pack is fairly vanilla.  The reason I was asking this though was that I was wanting to make an East-Asian castle/pagoda-looking building on a server that's fairly restrictive against mods, and it looks like a resource pack would not affect what other players see.

Comment: Custom texture pack...

Comment: @Ben Sorry, I forgot to mention vanilla.  Thanks though.

Comment: The closest you might be able to come is a plain [quartz block](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:Block_of_Quartz.png)...

Comment: @Panzercrisis Using resource pack is considered vanilla...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of 1.8, in un-modded and un-textured minecraft, there is no block that fits your requirements. Probably the closest you'd come is a [Snow Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow), a [Wool Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool), a [Quartz Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Quartz), or, as you said, an [Iron Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_block). The Quartz is extremely close to pure white, closer than the iron block. However, you should look into downloading a texture or a mod that may include a purely white block if none of these are close enough.

Comment: The [quartz block](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:Block_of_Quartz.png) might also work well...

Comment: Maybe also white wool, although it has some kind of textured look.

Answer (score 4):

There is no pure white block in Minecraft. Sorry.

However, you could edit your texture pack to make a certain block white. But this wouldn't work for other players if you are map building (they would still see it as whatever block you placed).

Answer (score 4):

If you make an item frame with a comple map of white concrete you can make a white surface.
The SMPLive server did this.

Comment: Helpful tip: go above the bedrock in the nether and cover a few square areas with the color patterns you want. If you make maps of them then you essentially have custom textures for any block, although they are a little bigger than the actual block.

Answer (score 2):

(Similar to the above)

This is an example of what I did: In a **resource pack**, I turned wool blocks to the plain colour they are, no textures at all. If you wanted a plain white block you may need to get a **Resource/texture** pack or **mod**.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, you intend to show others your architecture. And would like for it to look the same as what you would see if you used a resource pack.

1. If you intend to share it as a world file, you should share your resource pack together with the world file for the other user to apply as well.
2. If this is on a server, and you host the server, then an alternative would be to set server side resource pack for the user to automatically download when they join the server. This can be easily done by uploading the resource pack to a public file sharing site such as dropbox and providing the direct download link in your server.properties file.

Hopefully this gives you a solution that allows you to expand beyond the vanilla textures and still share your creation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still coming across this question, you're probably looking for white [concrete](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Concrete). You can create white concrete by crafting white [concrete powder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Concrete_Powder) (from sand, gravel and white dye) and placing it in water to harden it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Quartz Block. You will need 4 Nether Quartz. Use the default version of the Quartz Block,it is the most blank of the blocks,except perhaps the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry bro, I make a white block mod. You can download it in this link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/whitemod This mod adds a white dimension, a white block and an igniter to the dimension.